# How to Handle JQuery Ajax Result With Out Call Back Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, httpclient, client-side

I am using jQuery Ajax API to handle my CRUD operations. I encounter the situation that I want to call the server using AJAX but do not want to handle the result with a callback function. Is there any way to handle the result without using callback functions.

There is sample code describes what I want.

```
        if (ConfirmUserName(userName)) {
            return "User Already Exist";
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
```

The function used validates userName. Please note SendRequest method sends synchronous AJAX call to server.

```
function ConfirmUserName(userName) {
            var validate = false;
            SendRequest("/ClientUser/ValidateUserName", { ClientUserName: userName }, null, function (returnedData) {
                validate = returnedData;

            }, function () { }, null);
        return validate;
        }
```

Comment: You Can Do A Synchronous Ajax Call, But That Is Almost Always A Bad Idea. (OK, sorry, I'm being rude.) Is there some specific problem you're having with the callbacks? Perhaps a workaround could be suggested so that you can keep using them and keep everything nicely asynchronous.

Comment: Please Don't Capitalize Every Word, It's Very Annoying To Read.

Comment: How do you know you've got a response back from

Comment: How do you know you've had a response from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not expecting any output results from the Ajax request, you can simply ignore the `success` attribute. However, this will have its own implications.

Answer (score 0):

You will get confirmation of result from AJAX call only when the callback function is called.